# When I import this SVG into Photoshop it looks zoom pixelated, which didn't before

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, svg

I'm trying to import this SVG; which I imported before earlier but now it seems to don't work that well anymore? The original SVG file has not been modified, so I don't know where the issue could be, closing Photoshop didn't help. Illustrator doesn't have this issue.

[image]

It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

When you drag and drop the SVG inside you can choose a height and width and I choosed 1080 and it gave me that pixelated one. How can I fix it?

Comment: Since Photoshop is a pixel based application, imported vector graphics will always be "pixelated". *Rasterized* is the correct term. Whether it's visible or not depends on how many pixels you choose to make the rasterized version of the svg. But you say that you've made your document "1080". Do you mean that the width is 1080 px? Then it shouldn't look so blocky... Unless maybe the svg file has a lot of whitespace around the graphics?

Comment: @Wolff actually right, so I formed the question new, I call it "zoomed pixelated" now. It is not making it more HQ if you know what I mean. Even after restarting my PC

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. But tell me: The screenshot you have posted, is it viewed at 100% or is it zoomed in?

Comment: I drag and dropped it inside Photoshop and then a window pops up where you can define width and height and I changed it to 1080 and it shows like this, others do not except a few other svgs but not each of them. It should basically look like this https://i.imgur.com/J1RW5Qw.png

Comment: Yes, but 1080 what? Pixels? And please tell me if the screenshot is seen at 100%? You can double-click the zoom tool (magnifying glass) to see the image at 100%.

Comment: In there I type 1080: https://i.imgur.com/9TYMqqr.png

Comment: And this is how it looks like https://i.imgur.com/x7qQKNC.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99432/discussion-between-wolff-and-karl-police).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVG that I had contained `<g enable-background="new">` which I turned into `<g>` and fixed the issue. And I didn't lose anything from the SVG. Apparently the plugin that was used generated the SVGs like that and there was that one small issue I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The property was part of the SVG 1.X specification, but has since been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/enable-background). It was specifically meant to enable effect inheritance for children of the element. In your case, probably the drop shadow of the silver foreground item onto the item in the background.

So, if you export to any SVG between 1.1 and 2.0, you will get this property on any element with effects, such as drop shadows.

I'm not exactly sure why Photoshop would consider it a raster image, although it's understandable that a program not designed to handle vector images would have trouble handling specs that are five years old.